# navigate to particular url in a href ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have website field in my table I bind the data using ng-bind when I click the website link it should to that website. How to achieve it.

[image: website]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: What code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

use `<a ng-href="YOURURL"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Here,$scope.GetCustomerDetail.Website has website(www.google.com)  when I click the link it should go for google page. But it does not happen. Because we need to add http:// before the websitename. When I store the website with http://www.google.com format in database . It will navigate to that page.